# MongoDB if sub array search if not then do this

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a radio station that wants a program grid made, and instead of inputting the show info and the show on air times in different collections / databases I want to do the array input for MongoDB using PHP to store it like the following:

```
array{
    "showname"=>"title of show", 
    "pagelink"=>"showtitle"  
    "onairdays"=>array(
        "monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday"
     ), 
     "onairtime"=> "22:00", "endtime"=> "01:00"
)
```

But if a show is only on for one day per week I want it to look like this

```
array{
    "showname"=>"title of show",
    "pagelink"=>"showtitle" 
    "onairdays"=>"monday", 
    "onairtime"=> "22:00", 
    "endtime"=> "01:00"
)
```

The PHP query needs to search day and time and it does this by *PHP Melbourne/Australia* getting the day in full text lowercase and the time in 24 hour format

I have tried the following

```
$document = $collection->findOne(array("day"=>$day, "start"=> array('$gte' =>  date('Hi'))));
```

but it does not work until I do the following

```
$document = $collection->findOne(array("day"=>$day, "start"=> array('$gte' => print  date('Hi'))));
```

But that prints out the time then the array.

Comment: For my money I would keep even the single day entries as arrays as it is easier to change them if the "programming" changes for an item. At any rate MongoDB would allow you to index the mixed types, but keeping the same types on the same fields is better practice than mixing. Not too hot on the times as strings, but in any rate you will need to do some juggling when crossing a "day" boundary. But really, what is your actual question? Do want a query to do this? What have you actually tried?

Comment: My Issue will be how to query the hours. I am not sure I know how to go "day"=>"Monday" - but I am unsure how to query the time because it has to be for example say a show started at 0700 and it is now 0710 how do i make it now to find the show that is more or equal to 0700 and less then the end time